# Calculating results of a Coin Flip with dynamic odds based on the numbers of flips so far

Tags: statistics

Suppose you have a coin which instead of having 50:50 chance of Heads v Tails you have a A:B chance. At the start A is 0 and B is 100 so there is no way to land on heads, but each time you flip it, after each flip, A increases by 1 and B decreases by 1, so that the odds go:

```
0:100 <-first flip

1:99 <-second flip

2:98 <-third flip

3:97 <-fourth flip
```

How many flips will you have to do to land on heads?

I built a simple computer program to simulate this a few million times and I know the answer is around 14.2 flips, but I'm curious how you could actually solve this just with math, and ideally have a function that even lets you adjust variables such as how the odds adjust over each flip (suppose it increases by 2 points instead of 1 each flip, for example).

I've observed that adding the A value (of the A:B) odds for the first 14 flips (that is 0+1+2+...+13) gets you a number under 100 while adding the A value of 1 more flip gets you a total sum above 100, so this seems to indicate that the solution can be derived somewhere within this pattern... Not sure where it possibly goes from there though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the outcome of the $i$'th flip (zero-indexed), with $p_i:=P(X_i=1)=i/100$ and $P(X_i=0)=(100-i)/100$

Let $Y$ denote the random variable for when you see the first head. Thus for $n\in[0,99]$:

$$P(Y>n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1-p_i)=\frac{100!}{(100-n-1)!100^{n+1}},$$

and $P(Y>100)=0$. Then:

$$E[Y]=\sum_{n=0}^{100}P(Y>n)$$

which [numerically gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B100%21%2F%28%28100-n-1%29%21*100%5E%28n%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C100%7D%5D): $\approx 12.2$.

If you want to enumerate flips with not zero-indexing, then the answer is around 13.2 flips. You got 14.2 flips, so I wonder if there's a silly error above on my part.

Comment: Could have just as easily been an error in my code (which I’ve since deleted, oops!)

Comment: Just had a second coder make and run a simulation and he also got 14.21 so may be a small “bug” in the math. Either way just a “+1” seems to do the trick haha